# How can I check if a string has a numeric value in it in Python?

Tags: python, string, integer, converters

For example, I want to check a string and if it is not convertible to integer(with `int()`), how can I detect that?

Comment: There is already a solution here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-python

Comment: For clarity, should '-99' be allowed?  What about '+123'?  Or " 1729 "  (integer with leading and trailing spaces).  '0x123'?

Comment: @MarkDickinson -- why wouldn't `'-99'` be allowed?

Comment: @mgilson:  No idea---I can't guess what the OP's usecase is.  But it's an obvious example that isn't served so well by the 'isdigit' answer.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/python-parse-string-to-float-or-int

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use the [`.isdigit()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
>>> '123'.isdigit()
True
>>> '1a23'.isdigit()
False
```

Quoting the documentation:

> Return true if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, false otherwise.

For `unicode` strings or Python 3 strings, you'll need to use a more precise definition and use the [`unicode.isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#unicode.isdecimal) / [`str.isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal) instead; not all Unicode digits are interpretable as decimal numbers. [U+00B2 SUPERSCRIPT 2](http://codepoints.net/U+00B2) is a digit, but not a decimal, for example.

Comment: -1 for `a="0x12" `a.isdigit()` >>>False

Comment: I didn't downvote, but `" 1234".isdigit()` will return `False` even though `int` will happily ignore the space in the front.

Comment: @user1655481: that's not a number either, it's a python hex literal. `int('0x12')` throws ValueError unless you specify a base.

Comment: @mgilson: that's kind of the point of the function. It depends on your usecases as to what you need, if `.strip()` is needed, etc.

Answer (score 33):

You can always `try` it:

```
try:
   a = int(yourstring)
except ValueError:
   print "can't convert"
```

Note that this method outshines `isdigit` if you want to know if you can convert a string to a floating point number using `float`

Comment: Upvote. It's more pythonic to just try..except :)