# Converting list of long ints to ints

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, int

```
[112L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L]
```

How can I convert this list into a list of integer values of those mentioned values? I tried `int()` but it returned an error. Any idea guys?

Comment: What code gave you the error? What error was it? Please provide enough details for people to help you.

Comment: what error returned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a string has a numeric value in it in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466061/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-has-a-numeric-value-in-it-in-python)

Comment: Why do you want to convert the longs to integers? The list should work the same whether it contains integers or longs. Or are you just doing `print(my_list)`, and don't like the look of the 'L's?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You generally have many ways to do this. You can either use a list comprehension to apply the built-in [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function to each *individual* `long` element in your list:

```
l = [112L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L]

l2 = [int(v) for v in l]
```

which will return the new list `l2` with the corresponding `int` values:

```
[112, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126]
```

Or, you could use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), which is another built-in function, in conjunction with `int()` to accomplish the same exact thing:

```
# gives similar results
l2 = map(int, l)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use list comprehension and convert each element in the list to an integer. Have a look at the code below:

```
>>> l = [112L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L]
>>> i = [int(a) for a in l]
>>> print i
[112, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126]
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use `map`-

```
l = [112L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L]
print map(int,l)
```

Prints-

```
[112, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126]
```