# Check whether variable is int or long in Python 2.7 and 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to have a input type check for an API function that works in Python 2.7 and up. The API takes a timestamp in milliseconds since epoch as its parameter. I need to ensure that the input is a positive number.

Depending on the value, Python 2.7 will represent a timestamp as an `integer` or a `long`. So the type check would look like this:

```
isinstance(timestamp, (int, long))
```

However, the `long` type was merged with `int` for Python 3. In fact, the long type no longer exists. So the above line would cause an exception. Instead, the check would look like this:

```
isinstance(timestamp, int)
```

For compatibility with Python 2.7, I tried casting the timestamp to an int. However, the cast operation still returns a `long` if the value is outside of the `integer` range. This means the check will fail for any timestamp after `Sun Jan 25 1970 20:31:23`. See also the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33519688/converting-list-of-long-ints-to-ints).

What would be the best way to make this a generic check that works in both versions of Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The check against any integer number, use `numbers.Integral`:

```
isinstance(timestamp, numbers.Integral)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or follow this [cheat sheet](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#long-integers) for python 2-3 compatiable code

Just install `future` package: `pip install future`

```
# Python2
>>> x = 9999999999999999999999L
>>> isinstance(x, int)
False
>>> from builtins import int
>>> isinstance(x, int)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from the `six` package:

```
import sys

PY3 = sys.version_info[0] == 3

if PY3:
    integer_types = (int,)
else:
    integer_types = (long, int)

long_type = integer_types[0]
```

Then you can check with

```
if isinstance(value, integer_types):
```

and cast with

```
value = long_type(value)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check that the type of variable is **exactly** equals to intgiven then just do it using [`type()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/__builtin__.type) function:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info >= (3,0):
    long = int

type(v) in (int, long)
```

Comment: Use isinstance() instead of type().

Answer (score -2):

```
# This will works in both Python2, Python3
# Just check type of the variable and compare
import time
timestamp = time.time()

type(timestamp) == int
type(timestamp) == float
```