# How to convert integers in a list to int()?

Tags: python, string, list, math, int

I'm making a function that evaluates maths in a string. First, it takes the string and then converts it to a list.

I tried converting the entire array into an array of integers, but I run into an error when the array looks like this: `["hello",1,"*",2]` as everything isn't a number.

I want to only convert the integers in the array `["1","2","hello","3"]` to integers, so the array becomes `[1,2,"hello",3]`

That way, I can do maths on the integers and not have them treated as strings, as currently, when I do this:

```
1 + 2
```

I get `12` as the output.
I want `3` as the output.

Comment: Loop over the list and [check if each string value represents an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except) before converting. Something like `new_list = [int(x) if is_int(x) else x for x in my_list]` where can use the `is_int()` function from the post I linked.

Comment: You haven't shown any code, and what is supposed to happen with `"hello"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a string has a numeric value in it in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466061/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-has-a-numeric-value-in-it-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with  [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) and [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
ls = ["1", "2", "hello", "3"]
new_ls = [int(n) if n.isdigit() else n for n in ls]
print(new_ls)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> [1, 2, 'hello', 3]
> ```

You can also add [`str.lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) to make it work with negative numbers:

```
ls = ["1", "-2", "hello", "-3"]
new_ls = [int(n) if n.lstrip('-').isdigit() else n for n in ls]
print(new_ls)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> [1, -2, 'hello', -3]
> ```